# Setting object to url in a custom manner

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

I am trying to create my own sort of "state" routing and am struggling with the manipulation of the URL. I have all the working parts for saving the state as an object and such, but I need to turn that object into a URL. So for reference, here is what my object looks like :

```
 urlObject = 
 [ 
  {"module":"module1",
    "customUrl":[{"mod1":["1","2"]},{"mod2":["1","2"]}]
  },
  {"module":"module2",
   "customUrl":[{"mod3":["true","false"]},{"mod4":["5","6"]}]
  }
 ]
```

So right now I am just doing a simple

```
 $location.search(JSON.stringify(urlObject));
```

To toss it in the URL. It would be neat if there were some way to format that, parse the URL formatting in my own way, so like It would change to like

```
/module1="module1sobject/module2="module2object"
```

When I say module2sobject, I mean the customUrl inside that object--so in that case it would be [{"mod1":["1","2"]},{"mod2":["1","2"]}]. I'm wondering if I could get some guidance on how to begin this process of setting and getting the object out of a url like this (specifically for use in my angular controllers).

Comment: Lets get a little more specific. For example sake, lets say your top view in 'users', and your route looks like 'users/:userId', and then your subview is either about or album, so your route looks like 'users/:userId/:whichPage. Are you trying to get what :userId and :whichPage is? Can you give a real example and show what the link would look like?

Comment: @chapinkapa So I am not really sure what the link would look like, it doesn't matter too much to be honest, slash separation by module would be most ideal. Each module represents its own module in angular and the states therein. So the if they slashes could separate the modules and then have the entire object for each module to be pulled out (and parsed ) as an object.

Comment: @chapinkapa so like /module1 = "JSON.stringify(module1.customUrl)" /module2 = " the object inside could be url encoded and pulled out or whatever is best to be honest (I'm not sure). I basically want to have a parse function where I pass the module name "module1" for example, and get back the customUrl inside of it via the url.